# MATLAB: Reading returned array of java objects

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-java

I have an custom java object that returns an array of `Thing` java objects. How can I convert and iterate over the returned array as java objects in matlab? Currently, it doesn't look like the returned array is being treated as java objects.

```
//Thing.java
public class Thing {

    public int x,y,z;
    public int[][] board;
    // constructors and setters etc.
}

//ThingReturner.java
public class ThingReturner {
    private LinkedList<Thing> mQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public void putThing(int x, int y, int z, int[][] board) {
         mQueue.add(new Thing(x, y, z, board));
    }

    public Thing[] getThings() {
        Thing[] things = new Thing[mQueue.size()];
        while (!mQueue.isEmpty()) {
            mQueue.pop();
        }
        return things;
    }
}
```

In my MATLAB code, I have:

```
javaaddpath '../bin/';
obj = javaObjectEDT('ThingReturner');
obj.putThing(4,6,0,[[1,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,1]]);
obj.putThing(2,2,1,[[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]);
>> obj.getThings()

ans =

Thing[]:
    []
    []
```

Calling `isjava(ans(1))` returns 0  (`isjava(ans)` returns 1 though). So how do I properly use the result of `getThings()` so I can use `ans(1).getX()` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake in my Java code, it should be:

```
public GameOfLifeThing[] getThings() {
    GameOfLifeThing[] things = new GameOfLifeThing[mGoLQueue.size()];
    int i =0;
    while (!mGoLQueue.isEmpty()) {
        things[i++] = mGoLQueue.pop();
    }
    return things;
}
```